# slider fading a toggle based on class

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-animate

I'm making a slider and am trying to write something for the thumbnails so when one is clicked it fades in adn the rest fade out.  I was trying to do it with classes, so they all have the class hide and I was trying to do an onclick all divs with the hide class fade out and then the div that was click fades in.

```
$("#figure_lymph_blue").click(function(){
$("#standards_container_total").animate({
marginLeft: -2251
}, 750 );
figure_fadeout();
figure_fadein();
});


function figure_fadeout() {
$(".hide").animate({
    "opacity":      "0.0",
    "-moz-opacity": "0.0",
    "filter":       "alpha(opacity=0)"    
}, 450);
}

function figure_fadein() {
$(this).animate({
    "opacity":      "1.0",
    "-moz-opacity": "1.0",
    "filter":       "alpha(opacity=100)"    
}, 450);
}
```

For some reason the fade in function doesn't work but the fadeout works fine, I don't understand why.  Maybe there's a better way to do it?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle to explain the issue better? You should use this tool http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I actually have one but it's for the whole slider, that's the snippet that's specific to this question above, and here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wp9jB/23/

Comment: Why not use `fadeToggle` instead of `animate`? http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadetoggle